# Angular HTML5 mode with WordPress, refreshing the page leads to 404

Tags: angularjs, wordpress

I am using routing in my angular app to load urls. This works perfectly when I click links from inside the app, but when I try to go directly to an app url, the server returns a 404.

Here is my code:

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
        .when('/booking', {
            templateUrl: 'wp-content/themes/myapp/pages/begin.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        });
});
```

My header has `<base href="/myapp/">` at the top, within the head tags.

I have read that this is an apache rewrite issue, so I tried modifying my .htaccess to include the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myapp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /myapp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, this does not seem to make a difference other than redirecting to the 404 page. I am using WAMP and localhost.

How do I make it so that refreshing the app or linking directly to the page will work?

Comment: server have to send to client index.html (or php) to url underneith, (not redirect), unless the real file is exists.

Comment: some similar post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224012/angular-js-routes-not-working-on-wamp

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'wp-content/themes/myapp/pages/index.html',
    controller: 'indexController'
  })
.when('/booking', {
        templateUrl: 'wp-content/themes/myapp/pages/begin.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you changed your WP permalinks?

In my case changing the Permalinks Settings to

```
/blog/%postname%/
```

or

```
/%postname%/
```

fixed it.

Also, please make sure to declare your `base href` at the top of the `<head>` section in your `index.*` file. I recommend using this script:

`<base href="<?php $url_info = parse_url( home_url() ); echo trailingslashit( $url_info['path'] ); ?>">`

Answer (score 0):

Check the page link from the Dashboard > Pages > "YOUR PAGE" and click the view option.
Verify this URL if it's matched with the error page URL.
If it'c changed just replace the URL with correct one.