# Get Apache VHost to load index.html instead of web directory

Tags: angularjs, apache, server, wamp, host

I'm having no luck finding this question answered so I'm asking this myself.

To get my VHost working, I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224012/angular-js-routes-not-working-on-wamp/28224697#28224697). My (working) "httpd-vhosts.conf" file looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin jesuscc1993@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "Z:/Projects/Web/MetalTxus Site"
    ServerName metaltxus.test
    ServerAlias www.metaltxus.test
    <Directory "Z:/Projects/Web/MetalTxus Site">
        #Options FollowSymLinks
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

As far as I know, I should change "Indexes" with "-Indexes" to make the web load "index.html" instead of the web directory.

However, when I did that, my WAMPServer wouldn't start. It would if I removed "FollowSymLinks" option but then all I got was a "403 - Forbidden" page ("you don't have permission to access "/" on this server").

As looking for a solution got me nowhere, I used this as my last resource.

I'm using latest WampServer version in Windows 8.1. I want to test an AngularJS application.

If you need any more information, go ahead and ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin jesuscc1993@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "Z:/Projects/Web/MetalTxus Site"
    ServerName metaltxus.test
    ServerAlias www.metaltxus.test
    <Directory "Z:/Projects/Web/MetalTxus Site">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The `Require all granted` is Apache 2.4 syntax where you were using Apache 2.2 syntax when using

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
```

Now all you need to do is place a file called `index.html` or `index.php` in the "Z:/Projects/Web/MetalTxus Site" folder.

I would suggest removing the space in the folder name `MetalTxus Site` its not absolutely necessary but it removes another possible complexity.

Also if you dont actually mean to give access to the site to *The Universe* try using

```
Require local
```

And if you want to be able to access the site just from other PC's on your internal network use

```
Require local
Require ip 192.168.1
```

ADDITIONAL SUGGESTION:

Also check httpd.con has thi sline uncommented

```
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
```

An has this

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Tried with:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin jesuscc1993@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "Z:/Projects/Web/MetalTxus"
    ServerName metaltxus.test
    ServerAlias www.metaltxus.test
    <Directory "Z:/Projects/Web/MetalTxus">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

It works exactly the same as before. Using

`Options -Indexes`

still gives me

`Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

Comment: If `index.html` exists in the correct folder it will be run instead of doing a directory listing. so either `index.html` is not its real name or its in the wrong folder. If you use notepad to edit this file its probably actually called `index.html.txt` turn on full extension view in explorer.

Comment: It's got the proper name and extension. It works fine in [the online server](http://metaltxus.altervista.org/). Here's a [screenshot of what the directory on local looks like](http://i63.photobucket.com/albums/h151/MetalTxus/directory.gif).

Comment: The web on the server is an old version without angular though. The important fact is that it's loading `index.html`.

Comment: It's got both features enabled.

Comment: My fault. I dunno what I was doing wrong but after playing for a bit with the settings I got it working with the ones you provided.